# Can't you install socket.io as a global package?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I tried to install socket.io with the `-g` switch

```
npm install -g socket.io
```

[and it installed correctly I think.](http://pastebin.com/qqSfNGC6)

but running the app it throws the cannot find module error.

Local install, i.e. if socket.io is present in node_modules in my project/package, works though.

So can't it be installed globally?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of global installation. It allows you to access packages directly from your console. But if you want to `require` package into your own application, you should add it as a dependency into your `packaje.json` and install it locally.

Here is the quotation from [npm documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html):

> - Install it locally if you're going to require() it.
> - Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

When you install a package globally, what you're saying is that you want to use it in your shell (cmd.exe). Something like `nodemon` is such a package that you would install globally but not include locally as it doesn't need to be included for your app to run, but instead is used to benefit you as the developer.

You install packages without the `-g` switch when it is necessary for your app to run. In this case it is necessary for socket.io to be installed. Note that locally installed packages should go into your `packages.json` file so that anyone who installs your app at a later date automatically gets the included packages. Global packages do not appear here.